# How to resolve "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is not executing while notification receiving in ios swift 4

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift4

in my case, I am using FCM for push notification I did all the code in the app delegate but problem is that when I send the notification from fcm it works successfully but when I trigger from the PHP side this not working and "didReceiveRemoteNotification" is not executing.
this is code which I have done.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications
import BRYXBanner

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var strDeviceToken:String = ""
    var isView = ""
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (isGranted, err) in
                guard isGranted else { return }
                self.getNotificationSettings()
                if err != nil {
                    //Something bad happend
                } else {
                    print(" if err != nil else......")
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

                    }
                }
            }
             UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
             FirebaseApp.configure()
          if Global.isInternetAvailable(){

            }else{
                Global.showAlertMessageWithOkButtonAndTitle(GlobalConstant.APP_NAME, andMessage: "Check Your Internet")
            }



            IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
            IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
            IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true



            // create viewController code...
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            /// Introduction Navigation Controller
            let TeamViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swr1") as! SWRevealViewController
            let BossViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swr") as! SWRevealViewController
            /// Login Navigation Controller

            let selectUserTypeViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SlideShow") as! SlideShowViewController

            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            // Frist Launch of App check the NSUserDefault
            let isFirstLaunch = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin) == nil
            if (isFirstLaunch)
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set("00", forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }

            // Check the isLogin
            let isUser = Global.getStringValue(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_type") as AnyObject)
            print(isUser)

            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin) as! String == "1"
            {
                if isUser == "t"{
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(TeamViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }else{
                    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(BossViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin) as! String == "00"
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.set("0", forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin)
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(selectUserTypeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(selectUserTypeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            return true
        }

       func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)
        {

            print("Firebase registration token::::::?????????????: \(fcmToken)")
           UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "deviceToken>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
        }


        func getNotificationSettings() {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() })
            }
        }

        func application(application: UIApplication,
                         didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
        }

        func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        }

        func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

            Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true//false


        }

        func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

        }

        func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        }

        func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

        }


        // Called when APNs failed to register the device for push notifications
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
            // Print the error to console (you should alert the user that registration failed)
            print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
        {
            print("didReceiveRemoteNotificationv User Info = ",userInfo)


            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadChatTableView"), object: nil)


            GlobalConstant.notificationDict = userInfo

            let notificationDictionary: NSDictionary = GlobalConstant.notificationDict?["aps"] as! NSDictionary
            let type: String = Global.getStringValue(notificationDictionary.value(forKey: "type") as AnyObject)

            //        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)

            var aps: [AnyHashable: Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [AnyHashable : Any]

            /// Check the isLogin
            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin) as! String == "1"
            {
                if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background
           {            }

            }
            else
            {
                let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let loginNav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(nibName: "LoginNavigationController", bundle: nil)
                let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                loginNav.viewControllers = [loginViewController]
                self.window?.rootViewController = loginNav
            }
        }

        // MARK:- UNUserNotificationCenter Delegate // >= iOS 10

        //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
        @available(iOS 10.0, *)
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            print(" willPresent User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadChatTableView"), object: nil)

            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

            var aps: [AnyHashable: Any] = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! [AnyHashable : Any]

            /// Check the isLogin
            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin) as! String == "1"
            {

            } //====
            else
            {
                let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let loginNav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(nibName: "LoginNavigationController", bundle: nil)
                let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                loginNav.viewControllers = [loginViewController]
                self.window?.rootViewController = loginNav
            }
        }

        //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
        @available(iOS 10.0, *)
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print("didReceive User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
            completionHandler()
            var aps: [AnyHashable: Any] = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! [AnyHashable : Any]
    //        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

            /// Check the isLogin
            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: GlobalConstant.kkIsLogin) as! String == "1"
            {
                if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive || UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    let banner = Banner(title:GlobalConstant.APP_NAME , subtitle: aps["alert"] as? String, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-3"), backgroundColor: Global.hexStringToUIColor("#F3AF41"))
                    banner.springiness = .heavy
                    banner.position = .top
                    banner.didTapBlock =
                        {

                    }
                    banner.show(duration: 3.0)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let loginNav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(nibName: "LoginViewController", bundle: nil)
                let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
                loginNav.viewControllers = [loginViewController]
                self.window?.rootViewController = loginNav
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: please help me any one

Comment: Maybe the push isn't sent from PHP at all? You have to make sure that you have implemented the back-end properly

Comment: yes i have checked. now "willPresent notification" Method is executing but "didReceive response"  is not executing plz check my code which are given Above.

Comment: As you mentioned, when you sent from FCM console it is working but from PHP backend is not working. When you execute the PHP notification do you receive the Push notification? Can you add your PHP code?